# Variable length arguments in TestNG Method

Tags: java, testng

I have been writing the tests in TestNG. My aim is to provide variable length arguments to the test method. I am facing a problem which is not making any sense to me. The codes are as follows:

```
@DataProvider(name = "testData")
public static Object[][] testDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
        {
            "hello",
            "bye"
        }
        {
            "hey"
        }
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testData", DataProviderClass = TestData.class)
public void test(String... strings) {
    if (strings.length == 1) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This code gives me `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
  1 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
  2     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  3     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  4     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  5     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  6     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
  7     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
  8     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
  9     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
 10     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
 11     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
 12     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
 13     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
 14     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
 15     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
 16     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
 17     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
 18     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 19     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 20     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
 21     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
 22     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
 23     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
 24     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
 25     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Could somebody please tell me why is this error coming and how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: In my case, changing Object[][] -> String[][] helped. This is basically the same that @Anuragh27crony suggested, but saves you from typing 'new String[]' all the time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try to use proper array initialization and it should work.
I tried the same code just with correct array initialization and it worked.

```
@DataProvider(name = "testData")
    public static Object[][] testDataProvider() {
        return new Object[][] {
            new String[]{ "abc", "abcd" },
            new String[]{ "abc", "abcd", "123" }
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "testData")
    public void test(String... str) {
        System.out.println("The Length is" + str.length);

    }
```

Also attaching the TestNG results...
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This is indeed the working way to solve the problem when the test method has only a single parameter and that parameter is vararg.

Answer (score 0):

The current TestNG 6.8.8 does not support multiple providers per test method, and from the point of view of TestNG the test declaration annotation in the form of @Test(dataProvider = "testData, testData2") means that there should be a data provider named "testData, testData2", not that there are two providers named "testData" and "testData2".

After that, there is a bug in how TestNG handles vararg methods. The source code in question is https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/Invoker.java#L1358, where, as you can see, the TestNG will basically add the whole parameters arrays as the last parameter. There are related pull requests https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/456 and https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/459.

The work-around: just use explicit array-based parameters, for example:

```
@DataProvider(name = "testData")
public static Object[][] testDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
            {
                    new String[]{"a", "b"}
            },
    };
}

@Test( dataProvider = "testData" )
public void test( String[] strings ) {
}
```

If you really need verarg test method then, until the bug in the TestNG is fixed, you are left with a single vararg parameter only and with the Object as vararg base type:

```
@DataProvider(name = "testData")
public static Object[][] testDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
            {
                    // values of any type that will be wrapped into a single vararg parameter
                    456, "string", "another string", 456
            },
    };
}

@Test( dataProvider = "testData" )
// single vararg parameter
public void test( Object... values ) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the concern is something different - passing variable length arguments in the test. I have also modified the question for the same.

Comment: Array Based explicit parameters are also not helping

Comment: Explicit array-based parameters in the from shown in my answer do work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is set your varagrs as Object-type and cast to String type on @Test

```
@Test(dataProvider = "testData")
public void test(Object... args) {
    String data0=(String) args[0];
}
```

Hope this help!