# @DataProvider returns 100 column values

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I am using TestNG framework for my automation. DataProvider method returns 100 column values(data needed for test) for each row from Excel sheet.I need to use them in my @Test. How do i pass 100 parameters in @Test method?Is there any easy way to do it? It is difficult to write 100 parameters in @Test method. Any other way of doing it?

```
@DataProvider(name="InputData")
public Object[][] InputData() throws IOException
{
    Object[][] data = testData(dataFile,"Sheet1");
    return data;
}


@Factory(dataProvider = "InputData")
public A_Test(String a,String b, , , , , , , , , , , )
{

        this.stream=a;
        this.Keyword=b;

}
```

Comment: Wrap them into an array/object?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks. Did u mean to wrap them in InputData() method? It is already an Object Array. The problem here is with accepting arguments which is of huge size.It would be great if you could  write up a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass varaggs `String... str`

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "InputData")
public A_Test(String... str) {
}
```

Some things to consider

**1. Big, unreadable test reports**

Every invocation is logged separately, with all parameters. It becomes unreadable even with about 5 parameters and about 50 invocations.

**2. Exception handling**

Doing complex logic in data provider is not an good idea. When exception occurs in `@DataProvider` all tests using it are skipped.
When you read Excel file in `@DataProvider` it may fail because of file not found, file too big, wrong file format, etc.

Most likely, you prefer those tests to fail, so your build would fail too. See http://rolf-engelhard.de/2011/10/fail-instead-of-skip-a-test-when-testngs-dataprovider-throws-an-exception/ for possible solutions. For me Solution 1 (test for data provider) or 2 (return empty array on exception) makes most sense.

Comment: Thank you Bartosz.                                                                             
 When i tried your solution.                  
        @DataProvider(name="InputData")
 public Object[][] InputData() 
 {
  Object[][] data = testData(dataFile,"Sheet1");
  return data;
 } 
 @Factory(dataProvider = "InputData")
 public A_Test(String... str)
 { 
   this.stream=str.stream;
          this.Keyword=str.keyword;      
 }    str.stream cannot be fetched.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007276/variable-length-arguments-in-testng-method for more details for using varagrs. there are some gotchas. also. see my 'things to consider' and consider if you are into varargs at all in your case.

Comment: in my example String... str is array. so you need to do stream=str[0]; keyword=str[1]; etc.

Comment: A_Test can only accept 100 parameters. If i enter String... str, i get an error Ïncorrect number of arguments. Am i missing something here. Kindly clarify.

Comment: `String...` is like `String[]`. So your dataprovider must provide only 1 array param with your 100 params into it.

Comment: Hi Bartosz, String... works with @Test method and shows 3 Tests have been run in the report. So i decided not to use Factory method as it did not work there. Thank you for the introducing varags to me..It was very helpful. Thanks juherr for your comments too.

Comment: I also used Solution 2 for the risk associated with Data Providers:)